# fastify setErrorHandler return only string or blank object

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

in my code setErrorHandler return only string or blank object

```
server.setErrorHandler(async (error, req, reply) => {
    reply.status(200).send("I am response");
});

response content - type html / plain with string 'I am response'

server.setErrorHandler(async (error, req, reply) => {
    reply.status(200).send({
        ok: false
    });
});

response content - type application / json with json '{}'

server.setErrorHandler(async (error, req, reply) => {
    reply.status(200).send({
        error: {
            status: true,
            message: constant.FATAL_ERROR,
            errorCode: constant.FATAL_ERROR_CODE
        }
    });
});

response content - type application / json with json {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "code": "FST_ERR_FAILED_ERROR_SERIALIZATION",
    "message": "Failed to serialize an error. Error: "
    error " is required!. Original error: "
    error " is required!"
}
```

can anyone give me right code so i can send full json

i need full json as i passed in reply.send()

Comment: Did you set some `schema`s on your route?

Comment: yes i have validation schema

Comment: Could you add them to the question? the `FST_ERR_FAILED_ERROR_SERIALIZATION` explains that the issue is on the schemas

Comment: but my first and second case not give `FST_ERR_FAILED_ERROR_SERIALIZATION` on same request

Comment: The first one because it is a string, and a string is never serialized (it is already serialized tho). The second one because you don't have the error property that depends on the schema. Do you want to add the schema to the question?